# How to coordinate this behavior in react-saga?

Tags: javascript, redux-saga

I am saving an entity.

I want to trigger a synchronous `savePending` (triggers a reducer against the store), and then an asynchronous `save` operation (makes the network call to make the save).

```
function * saveEntity({ paylpoad: { id, name } }) {
  yield put (savePending()); // triggers a synchronous reducer
  yield put (save()); // triggers an async saga
  yield put (saveComplete());
}
```

Will redux-saga wait for `savePending` to complete (ie. for the reducer to complete running against the store) before moving on to `save`? (presumably yes).

Will redux-saga wait for **all** reducers and sagas associated with an action emitted by a `put` (eg `save`) even if they are asynchronous, before moving onto the next `yield` (eg `saveComplete`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as you expect, the `savePending()` reducer will run as soon as the `put (savePending())` effect is yielded.

On the other hand, no, the `yield put (save())` call will not wait for the save to complete.

I imagine you've got code something like this:

```
const save = () => { type: SAVE_ACTION };

function * watchSave() {
  yield takeEvery(SAVE_ACTION, doSave);
}

function * doSave() {
    // [async saving logic]
}
```

When you yield your `save` action, it will trigger a call to your reducer (which will likely do nothing, if your save action is only used to trigger a saga), but there's no way for your `saveEntity` saga to know to wait for the `saveSaga`, which was triggered from the `save` action.

There's a few ways to fix that.  One would be to write your code like this:

```
function * saveEntity({ paylpoad: { id, name } }) {
  yield put (savePending());
  yield call (doSave());
  yield put (saveComplete());
}
```

By calling the `saveSaga()` directly, `saveEntity` will wait for the `saveSaga()` to complete before moving on.

---

On the other hand, if you want to keep `saveEntity` and `saveSaga` less coupled, you could have `saveSaga` emit an action which `saveEntity` can listen for:

```
function * watchSave() { /* as before */ }

function * doSave() {
  // [async saving logic]
  yield put(saveCompleted()); // Indicate that the save is completed
}

function * saveEntity({ paylpoad: { id, name } }) {
  yield put (savePending());
  yield put (save());
  // Wait for the saveSaga to be done:
  yield take (saveComplete());
}
```